# There is a double dot between `numbersection` and `numbertheorem`

Tags: sectioning, theorems

I want the section numbering to be `numberchapter.numbersection.` So I type

```
    \renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}.}
```

But if I want to make a theorem, the theorem numbering is displaying `Theorem numberchapter.numbersection..numbertheorem`. There is a double dot between `numbersection` and `numbertheorem`. How can I have it show a single dot only?

```
    \documentclass[twoside,11pt]{book}
    \usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,papersize={15.5cm,23.5cm}]{geometry}
    \renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
    \renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}.}
    \renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.}
    \usepackage{amsthm}
    \newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
    \newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
    \begin{document}
        \chapter{ABC}
        blablabla
        \section{ONE}
        \begin{theorem}
            dddd
        \end{theorem}
    \end{document}
```

**EDIT:**

Based on Egreg's answer, if I format the section and subsection, the dot is not appear. Why this is can happen and what the solution?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsthm,titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}
[hang]
{\bfseries}
{\bfseries\thesection}{1ex}{\bfseries}
\titlespacing{\section}{1.5pt}{0.2cm}{0.2cm}

\titleformat{\subsection}
[hang]
{\bfseries}
{\bfseries\thesubsection}{1ex}{\bfseries}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{1.5pt}{0.2cm}{0.2cm}

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{%
    \ifcsname format#1\endcsname
    \csname format#1\endcsname
    \else
    \csname the#1\endcsname
    \fi
    \quad
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\formatsection}{\thesection.}
\newcommand{\formatsubsection}{\thesubsection.}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}}

\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]

\begin{document}
    
    \chapter{ABC}
    blablabla with \ref{sec:one} and no period.
    
    \section{ONE}\label{sec:one}
    
    \begin{theorem}
        dddd
    \end{theorem}
    
    \subsection{TWO}
    
    Just to see what happens.
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quite likely you don't want that cross-references to sections and subsections have the trailing period. So you don't want to hardwire the period in `\thesection` and in `\thesubsection`.

With the following code, the trailing period is added by `\@seccntformat`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{%
  \ifcsname format#1\endcsname
    \csname format#1\endcsname
  \else
    \csname the#1\endcsname
  \fi
  \quad
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\formatsection}{\thesection.}
\newcommand{\formatsubsection}{\thesubsection.}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}}

\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]

\begin{document}

\chapter{ABC}
blablabla with \ref{sec:one} and no period.

\section{ONE}\label{sec:one}

\begin{theorem}
dddd
\end{theorem}

\subsection{TWO}

Just to see what happens.

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you use `titlesec` it's even easier, because you can explicitly add the period in the right place.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsthm,titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}[hang]
  {\bfseries}
  {\thesection.}
  {1ex}
  {}
\titlespacing{\section}{1.5pt}{0.2cm}{0.2cm}

\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]
  {\bfseries}
  {\thesubsection.}
  {1ex}
  {}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{1.5pt}{0.2cm}{0.2cm}

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}}

\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]

\begin{document}

\chapter{ABC}
blablabla with \ref{sec:one} and no period.

\section{ONE}\label{sec:one}

\begin{theorem}
dddd
\end{theorem}

\subsection{TWO}

Just to see what happens.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have tried your code. But, if I format the section and subsection, the dot is not appear. Why this is can happen and what the solution? (See my edited question).

Comment: @OngkyDennyWijaya I added the code for `titlesec`. You should have mentioned its usage in the original post, but that's not a real problem.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
\renewcommand{\thetheorem}{\thesection\arabic{theorem}}
```